# WPF - User Interface "not working" in Windows XP

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-xp

I have a WPF app that works perfectly fine in Windows 7, but in Windows XP the interface does not work correctly at all.  I have several expanders that should all be closed and disabled upon launch, but all are open.  I have a button that should open a dialog, but the button does nothing.  Another button should be disabled, but appears in its natural state.  Further, my viewmodel does not appear to have loaded.  I tested it on an XP computer where it had this strange behavior for about 10 minutes.  I came back to it, re-ran, and it worked fine.  I didn't do anything to change it.  However, I cannot replicate this on other computers.  Any ideas?  I am using VS2010 with .Net 4 and MVVM Light framework.

Comment: What version of XP? Not all versions of .NET Framework work in all versions of XP.

Comment: Windows XP Pro -- it's definitely in this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/8z6watww(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I meant to ask if it was SP3. [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) The .NET 4 link says it has to be XP SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I thought it was a rendering problem, but it turns out that there was a silent error that caused the viewmodel to be null.  When I corrected the error, everything worked fine (though it still doesn't look very nice in XP).  Thank you all for the help!
I had initialization code that was supposed to read a registry key but when it did not find the registry key, it threw a null reference, but the error did not show up in the view (I was using a bug logging system that handled it, but the reporting was not properly configured).  When I corrected the error handling and initialization code, the view model was able to initialize and it worked fine.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your solution, so other SO users can benefit from in the future. Thanks.